# text is not clear after typing to send a message in Skype in Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: skype

I've searched around for all possible and popular bugs of Skype in Windows Phone 8.1 (and there are some same bugs with Windows Phone 10) but I could not find this strange bug listed.

Two colleagues of mine are experiencing this bug, it's just quite easy to describe the bug. Normally when you type a message, after tapping Send button, the message is sent ***and*** the typed message in the text box should be cleared and ready for user to type a new message. However with this bug, the message is not cleared. User has to delete the (old) message manually himself before being able to type a new message. That's so annoying and unacceptable bug.

I don't really know if this is listed somewhere on the net (maybe because I did not find the right key words to search for this) so I don't have any clue on how to fix this bug. I hope someone here has experienced this or at least knew about this and could give me some suggestion as well as some way to fix this nasty bug.

Comment: If you truly believe this is a bug, you should report it bug to Microsoft.

Comment: Skype works perfectly fine for myself and all my contacts. Sounds like something on your end only.